# Need help with reducing size of apt mirror server

Tags: apt, server

I've recently inherited the admin of a group of Ubuntu servers (20.04 LTS), including a local mirror server. It depleted over 1.5 TB size with full clone from official server. Could I adopt any method to reduce the size of apt mirror server? Although there are only at 20.04 and latest packages version. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A local full Archive mirror will be over 2TB in size currently - I can confirm this as an archive mirror runner myself.  Your other option would be to run an apt-cacher server, though I haven't done this in a long time - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server - though this needs some updates to work properly and you probably should be using apt-cacher-ng with a guide like this: https://kifarunix.com/install-and-configure-apt-caching-server-using-apt-cacher-ng-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 0):

I am maintaining my own mirrors as well.
My focal mirror is 238 GB in size. But I am syncing only the 64bit archives: update, main, restricted and security. multiverse I removed.

Maybe removing the 32bit archives could be an options to you.

In the mirror file then use:

```
deb-amd64 http://....
```

Comment: This isn't a total option - there ARE 32bit libraries still supported in system releases, for drivers and such, so not syncing 32bit libraries is going to cause some headaches.

Comment: Not true, I am running 64bit installations and mirror without headache since xenial. Since the user did not describe all perimeters it is guesswork if this solution works for him - agree - but it is one valid solution at all.

Comment: I am syncing only the 64bit archives: for all update, main, restricted, security and multiverse. Reduced 300G usage of disk space.

Comment: Would be great if you mark my answer then as valid and/or upvote. Thx